# Angular ng build not generating dist folder

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework

I've been working in an angular/ionic project, trying to deploy it to aws using S3 I'm unable to generate the `dist` folder when running the `ng build` or `ng build --prod` command, after many attempts I share my repo with you hoping I can get some help, also there are not errors shown at all in console and build is performed normally in logs.

https://github.com/biherrerap/fda_delivery_master

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read.

Comment: Could you please tell us exactly what is the error you're facing (error stacktrace) and where is the code throwing the error?

Comment: have you tried `ng build --prod` ?

Comment: @Mornor Thanks for your answer, there are not error logs shown at all.

Comment: @HansakaSandaruwan Thanks for your answer, yes, I've already tried that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `angular.json` you have specified the `"outputPath": "www"`. so your build is going in a folder called `www`. if u want it to go on a `dist` folder change angular.json file.projects->app->architect->build->options->outputPath to 'dist'